# SQL Query to Count IDs with Consecutive Status Followed by a keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data in my database:

[image]

I'm trying to write an SQL query that will count the Retailer IDs where the FSL Status is "Imputed" for three consecutive months, followed immediately by a "Projected" status. I want to include only those cases where the "Projected" status occurs right after three consecutive "Imputed" statuses.

Can someone help me construct this SQL query?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please show us your attempt so we can assist you with it.

Comment: And please show your desired results (but as formatted text *not* as an image).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: if you have 4 imputed and one projected, does it still counts? Since it's also after 3 imputed?

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant but it works:

```
select count(distinct a.RetailerId)
from MyTable a
inner join MyTable b
  on a.RetailerId = b.RetailerId
  and dateadd(month, -1, a.Period) = b.Period
  and b.[FSL Status] = 'Imputed'
inner join MyTable c
  on b.RetailerId = c.RetailerId
  and dateadd(month, -1, b.Period) = c.Period
  and c.[FSL Status] = 'Imputed'
inner join MyTable d
  on c.RetailerId = d.RetailerId
  and dateadd(month, -1, c.Period) = d.Period
  and d.[FSL Status] = 'Imputed'
where a.[FSL Status] = 'Projected'
```

In the select I put a count distinct, but Count(*) could be enough. You know the data, you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of cumulative sum `sum() over (order by ...)` to identify the required group (3 Imputed + 1 Projected).

`cte` identify the `grp`. `cte2` counts number of rows within the `grp`

```
with cte as
(
  select *, 
         grp = sum(case when Status = 'Imputed'   then 0
                        when Status = 'Projected' then 1
                        end) 
               over (partition by RetailerID 
                         order by Period desc)
  from   yourTable
),
cte2 as
(
  select *, cnt = count(*) over (partition by RetailerID, grp)
  from   cte
)
select *
from   cte2
where  cnt >= 4   -- 1 Projected & 3 Imputed
order by RetailerID, Period
```